# Why isn't my SQL query returning any results in hibernate?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

In my spring/hibernate application I'm using the following query to search for users to check if string variable *name* exists in any of their name:

```
    Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE CONCAT(user.name, user.middleName, user.lastName) LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%') ").setParameter("name", name).setMaxResults(20);
```

This returns no results. However when I run

```
SELECT * FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].User WHERE CONCAT(User.name, User.middleName, User.lastName) LIKE CONCAT('%','a','%')
```

in the MS SQL server, I get all users whose name contains 'a'.

What is going on?

Comment: You can enable hibernate logging to see the generated sql-query and parameters and compare them with your query. See Docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_sql_statement_logging

Comment: I've checked the hibernate logs, and it appears hibernate is converting CONCAT(User.name, User.middleName, User.lastName) into (user.name+user.middleName+ user.lastName) which doesn't return any rows in MSSQL either. Why is it doing this?

Comment: I can answer you why, but that won't help you - it's configured in the ```org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractTransactSQLDialect``` with the line ```this.registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "(", "+", ")"));```. I tried concat and + in sql - gives me the same results. Maybe some problem with different column types? Maybe you could add your relevant part of create table and some test-data?

Comment: So I found out  (user.name+user.middleName+ user.lastName) isn't working because the middleName column was null for all Users.. and null string wasn't being converted to '', an empty string. I guess CONCAT takes null values into account where + operator doesn't

Comment: Okay, you can try isnull in your JPQL. ```CONCAT(isnull(User.name, ''), isnull(User.middleName, ''), isnull(User.lastName, ''))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the hibernate logs, as Tom suggested, I found out hibernate converts CONCAT(string, string) into string+string, which should be the same but didn't work in my case because one of the string columns was NULL.

My solution in the end was change the query into

```
(user.name + ISNULL(user.middleName, '') + user.lastName)
```

Answer (score -1):

In HQl and SQL queries we cannot pass the value (:name) like this because it takes value during runtime. If you want to pass the value during the run time then you should try Criteria, It will definitely work.

Comment: That's not true.